# Can't use value returned by action in my component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex

My store action returns a value that I want to check when calling that action from my component. But for some reason, all I'm getting is `undefined` instead of any of the values I'm actually returning from any action.

Why?

Store action:

```
export const actions = {
  async initialize ({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
    await this.$axios.get('myEndpoint')
      .then((res) => {
        return true
      }).catch((error) => {
        return false
      })
  }
}
```

Component code:

```
async mounted () {
  const initializeResult = await this.initialize()
  console.log(initializeResult)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've to respect the vuex store pattern, First you should create a state that could be mutated inside a mutation which also could be committed inside the async callback in your action :

```
export const state={
  initResult:null
}

export const mutations={
    SET_RESULT(state,payload){
      state.initResult=payload
   }
}

export const actions = {
  async initialize ({ state, commit, dispatch }) {
    await this.$axios.get('myEndpoint')
      .then((res) => {
        commit('SET_RESULT',true)
      }).catch((error) => {
           commit('SET_RESULT',false)
      })
  }
}
```

then in your component dispatch the action inside the mounted hook and return the state using a computed property :

```
computed:{
    result(){
       return this.$store.initResult;
  }
},
mounted () {
  this.$store.dispatch('initialize')
 
}
```